# View all Desktop files in OpenFileDialog

Tags: windows, desktop

Upon launching an OpenFileDialog in a .NET application, the user is shown items from both the User and Public Desktop folders (the same as the actual Desktop):

[image: User and Public Desktop]

When the user decides to select the 'Desktop' Quick access shortcut or 'This PC > Desktop' from the side menu, the user is shown a different dialogue box that only shows the files saved in the User Desktop.

[image: User Desktop]

Is there a way for the user to manually select the first view again? (Excluding pressing the back button of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two tricks you can try:

ONE:

1. Navigate to a folder other than Desktop
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Type "Desktop" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

TWO:

In the address bar at the top of the dialog box, click on the leftmost breadcrumb ">" and from the menu that appears, select "Desktop" on the top.